# How to do a year to date count by week over a given date range

Tags: sql-server

I have a table consisting of an creation date, an id of the item created, and other unimportant information.  What I want to do is write a query that sums up items created year to date by week for a given date range.  So if I have this table:

```
ID   creationdate
--   ------------
 1   1/1/2015
 2   1/2/2015
 3   1/3/2015
 4   1/3/2015
 5   1/3/2015
 6   1/5/2015
 7   1/6/2015
```

And if I were to query for the date range of 12/29/2014 through 1/11/2015, I want to see these results:

```
weekof       count
------       -----
12/29/2014     5
 1/05/2015     7
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you get a total count of 12 with only 7 rows in your sample?  Please provide a complete sample table with your expected results taken from that sample.  It would also help if you provided an example of something you've already tried.

Comment: Total count is seven, not twelve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to calculate cumulative values on a table is to create a self join and connect the joined fields with the >= comparison operator.

It appears from you question that your week starts on a Monday.  Therefore, you will also need to calculate the immediate preceding Monday for each row in your table. In my solution, I calculated the name of the day using DATENAME and then subtract from the creation date the number of days the creation date is past Monday.

Finally, I formatted the date using the FORMAT function.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateTest]  ---Create Test Table DateTest
(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NULL
)
GO

---Insert Values
INSERT INTO
    DateTest
VALUES
    ('1','1/1/2015'),
    ('2','1/2/2015'),
    ('3','1/3/2015'),
    ('4','1/3/2015'),
    ('5','1/3/2015'),
    ('6','1/5/2015'),
    ('7','1/6/2015')
GO

---Perform the calculation
SELECT
    FORMAT(t1.StartOfWeek, 'd', 'en-US') as StartOfWeek, ----Render date as mm/dd/yyyy
    SUM(t2.CountForWeek) as CumulativeRecordCount
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        (CASE --Determine the most recent preceding Monday, because Monday is defined as the beginning of the week
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Sunday' THEN CreationDate-6
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Saturday' THEN CreationDate-5
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Friday' THEN CreationDate-4
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Thursday' THEN CreationDate-3
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN CreationDate-2
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN CreationDate-1
            ELSE CreationDate
        END) AS StartOfWeek,
        COUNT(id) AS CountForWeek
    FROM
        DateTest
    GROUP BY
        (CASE --Determine the most recent preceding Monday, because Monday is defined as the beginning of the week
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Sunday' THEN CreationDate-6
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Saturday' THEN CreationDate-5
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Friday' THEN CreationDate-4
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Thursday' THEN CreationDate-3
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN CreationDate-2
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN CreationDate-1
            ELSE CreationDate
        END)
    ) AS t1
INNER JOIN --Self Join Table
    (
    SELECT
        (CASE --Determine the most recent preceding Monday, because Monday is defined as the beginning of the week
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Sunday' THEN CreationDate-6
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Saturday' THEN CreationDate-5
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Friday' THEN CreationDate-4
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Thursday' THEN CreationDate-3
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN CreationDate-2
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN CreationDate-1
            ELSE CreationDate
        END) AS StartOfWeek,
        COUNT(id) AS CountForWeek
    FROM
        DateTest
    GROUP BY
            (CASE --Determine the most recent preceding Monday, because Monday is defined as the beginning of the week
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Sunday' THEN CreationDate-6
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Saturday' THEN CreationDate-5
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Friday' THEN CreationDate-4
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Thursday' THEN CreationDate-3
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN CreationDate-2
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,CreationDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN CreationDate-1
            ELSE CreationDate
        END)
    ) AS t2
    ON
    t1.StartOfWeek >= t2.StartOfWeek --- join t2.startofweek to all t1.startofweek dates greater than or equal to t2.startofweek
GROUP BY
    t1.StartOfWeek
```

### OUTPUT

```
StartOfWeek   CumulativeRecordCount
------------- ---------------------
12/29/2014            5
1/5/2015              7
```